# In image processing, Applying the convolution with guassian filter over image is same as the taking the guassian derivative over the image?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

For reducing the the noise we have to take the Gaussian derivative over the image right? Whether it is same as the applying the Gaussian kernel over the image? If yes,why are we using Gaussian kernel instead of taking the Gaussian derivative?

Comment: A Gaussian derivative (kernel) is not the same as a Gaussian (kernel). For smoothing, you want to apply the Gaussian kernel. For sharpening and edge extraction, you use the Gaussian derivative or some other derivative such as the Sobel filter or the difference of Gaussians (DoG). Mathematically, see https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/old/_media/courses/ucuws17/gd.pdf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function